# read Grammar from file and store in an array in C#

Tags: c#, automata

Still new to C# so be nice :)

```
S -> NP VP
S -> Aux NP VP
NP -> Proper-Noun
NP -> Nominal
Nominal -> Noun
Nominal -> Nominal Noun
Nominal -> Nominal PP
VP -> Verb NP
VP -> Verb NP PP
PP -> Preposition NP
```

how to store these productions in an array or in list in tabular form like following in c#.
above productions are read from file.

```
Table Structure
terminals -> all non terminals after that specific terminal
S -> NP VP Aux NP VP VP
VP -> Verb NP Verb NP PP Verb PP
```

Comment: I've created syntactic and lexical grammar parsers in C# and haven't the slightest clue what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ought to help:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Production
{
   public string Name;
   public string[] Components;

   public static IEnumerable<Production> Parse(string contents)
   {
      var rdr = new System.IO.StringReader(contents);
      string line;
      var productions = new List<Production>();
      while(null != (line = rdr.ReadLine()))
      {
         if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            continue;
         productions.Add(ParseOne(line));
      }

      return productions;
   }

   public static Production ParseOne(string line)
   {
      var parts = line.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      return new Production{Name = parts[0], Components = parts.Skip(2).ToArray()};
   }

}
```

You can use the Production.Parse method like so:

```
static void Main()
{      
   var productions = Production.Parse(@"S -> NP VP
S -> Aux NP VP
NP -> Proper-Noun
NP -> Nominal
Nominal -> Noun
Nominal -> Nominal Noun
Nominal -> Nominal PP
VP -> Verb NP
VP -> Verb NP PP
PP -> Preposition NP");
   // Or from a file like this:
   productions = Production.Parse(File.ReadAllText("myProductions.txt));
}
```

**Edit:** To join the productions, consider [grouping by](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) Name.

```
productions.GroupBy(p => p.Name, p => new Production{Name=p.Key, Components=p.SelectMany(x => x)});
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to have all of the components added to a singular list for the given terminal.  I think your post went above and beyond the call of duty though.

Comment: Ah.  Then productions.GroupBy ought to help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  On StackOverflow, another good way to thank those that have helped is to upvote helpful and accepting an answer by clicking a checkbox beside the helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo linq solution. It doesn't to any sort of error checking, and it assumes data is in an input file called lines.txt:

EDIT: Simplified the query

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("lines.txt");

            var results = from line in lines
                     let tokens = line.Split(' ')
                     group tokens by tokens.First() into tokenGroup
                     select new
                     {
                         Terminal = tokenGroup.Key,
                         NonTerminals = tokenGroup.SelectMany(tokens => tokens.Skip(2))
                     };

            foreach (var line in results)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder(string.Format("{0} ->", line.Terminal));
                foreach (var nonTerminal in line.NonTerminals)
                {
                    sb.Append(string.Format(" {0}", nonTerminal));
                }
                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            }
        }
```